# How to turn feature Picture in picture using javascript on firefox

Tags: firefox, picture-in-picture

I have searched my problem  but there is no solution, i have a video but i don't want user can seek or play, pause, i had block control video using js but with this feature i really false on my point, somebody could give me some advises to turn off that feature or hide element popup when hover video tag, i really try add attribute disablePictureInPicture or debug to find popup but look like firefox just get event when using mouse or touch, i check it on **firefox 72 beta** thank all.
[link image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spHyC.jpg)
ps/ My point is hidden or disable this button on firefox, i read on info release that feature is Picture in picture and released on firefox version 71 on window and version 72 on mac and linux

Comment: Please provide reference material,code snippet or file to review and understand your problem statement.

Comment: @Rizvan thank but I don't think my problem is my code, that feature is Picture in picture and released on firefox version 71 on window and version 72 on mac and linux, you can open youtube on firefox and you will see https://i.stack.imgur.com/spHyC.jpg